# Describing the right recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence

I've to describe a recurrence for l_n, the number of lobsters caught in year n

The task says: A hobby fisherman estimates the number of lobsters he will catch in a year as the average of the number he caught in the two previous years

Describe a recurrence for l_n, the number of lobsters caught in year n

I've tried something. It's degree-D homogeneous LRR so the recurrence is:
l_n = l_n-1 + l_n-2 as it's for 2 years. Have I solved ít correctly?

Comment: What do you think? Can you explain why what you have represents the average of the past two years? If not, perhaps there's a bug in your reasoning.

Comment: Your question is off-topic on this site. Ask it on http://math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths, not programming.

Comment: Sorry, I signed in on the wrong website o.O

Answer (score 0):

It's the average of the two, so you'd want to add them and divide by 2.

Comment: so add the 2 years and divide by 2 like this: l_n = (l_n-1 + l_n-2)/2